# Compare String without stop words PHP

Tags: php, keyword, string-comparison, stop-words

I want to compare 2 string without stop words like

LIKE terms, are ok or contains: example: "it's two" or "two" would be considered equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stopwords = array("it's", 'foo', '')
if (trim(str_replace($stopwords, "", $string1)) == $string2) print 'True'
```

Comment: That's pretty obvious solution. You just submited your answer before I did (after less the one minute).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a list of 'stop words'. You might be able to find one online, otherwise you'll have to set up one yourself.

Then it's fairly easy, use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace all occurrences of stop words and do your comparision thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework to me so i'll explain it in pseudo code to help you get going.

Define an array that contains all "stop words".

Split the strings you want to compare on empty spaces (" ")

Now iterate through the array you get, skipping all tokens that exist in the "stop words" array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
if ( strpos("it's two", "two") !== false ) {
  // string "two" found in "it's two"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. He wants to exclude stop words.

Comment: @Daniil Are you sure ? It returns position of the needle in the haystack. If not found - it's false.

Comment: @hsz sorry, I mean `int`, because documentation says it returns int, but then I noted Return Values section which says it can return False